# If you finished, we would have enjoyed

Tags: subjunctives

> If you finished this, we would have enjoyed that by now.

Does this sentence sound natural to you?

Answer (score 1):

That sentence should start "If you had finished *this*...". That would be a counterfactual set in the past, before the time that we would have enjoyed *that*. It implies that you didn't finish it.

Whether the sentence

> If you had finished this, we would have enjoyed that by now.

would be natural would depend on the context.